# Iterating through parameters of a variadic function template using variadic lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-functions

Suppose we have the following function template:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Arguments>
void IterateThrough(Functor functor, Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    // apply functor to all arguments
}
```

This function is usually implemented as follows:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Arguments>
void IterateThrough1(Functor functor, Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    int iterate[]{0, (functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), void(), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(iterate);
}
```

Another way:

```
struct Iterate
{
    template <typename... Arguments>
    Iterate(Arguments&&... arguments)
    {
    }
};

template <typename Functor, typename... Arguments>
void IterateThrough2(Functor functor, Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    Iterate{(functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), void(), 0)...};
}
```

I have found yet another approach which uses a variadic lambda:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Arguments>
void IterateThrough3(Functor functor, Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    [](...){}((functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), void(), 0)...);
}
```

What pros and cons has this method in comparison with first two?

Comment: Your struct constructor could use an ellipsis instead of a parameter pack.

Comment: @dyp Do you mean a simple variadic constructor? But wouldn't it violate the rule you have referenced below?

Comment: I mean `Iterate(...) {}`. The evaluation of the elements of a braced-init-lists is properly sequenced, so the "function argument evaluation order" argument is overruled for `Iterate{((void)functor(arguments), 0)...};`

Comment: @dyp I see now, thank you. Isn't the form `(void)functor(arguments), 0` dangerous due to the possible existence of `operator void()` in the class `decltype(functor(argument))`?

Comment: An `operator void()`? [Is that even possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe25d9d674f91a8f)? o.O

Comment: [class.conv.fct]/1 "A
conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to [...], or to (possibly cv-qualified) void." So you can declare one, but it's not going to be used. I conclude it won't cause any trouble.

Comment: @dyp So both clang 3.4 and g++ 4.8.2 have a bug, do they?

Comment: Why? As I said, you can declare it (probably for generic programming), but it's never called nor considered in overload resolution.

Comment: @dyp Yes, the behavior of both of them [corresponds to your words and quote](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/290d030b1cc5eb6c). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `functor` are now unsequenced. The compiler can call `functor` with your expanded arguments in any order it wants. As an example, `IterateThrough3(functor, 1, 2)` could do `functor(1); functor(2);` or it could do `functor(2); functor(1);`, whereas the other two always do `functor(1); functor(2);`.

Section 8.5.4/4 of the standard requires that any expressions inside a `{}` initialiser are evaluated left-to-right.

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack
>   expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear.

Section 5.2.2/4 states that arguments to a function call can be evaluated in any order.

> When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding
>   argument. [Note: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) —
>   end note ]

This might not cover the wording of the order of evaluation (which I can't find ATM), but it is well known that arguments to functions are evaluated in an unspecified order. EDIT: see @dyp's comment for a relevant standard quote.

Comment: Could you provide a quote from the standard to confirm your words, please?

Comment: @Constructor Is a non-normative note sufficient? 1.9/15 "[*Note:* Value
computations and side effects associated with different argument expressions are unsequenced. *— end note*]"

Comment: @Constructor See updated comment. The normative text does not, as far as I can see, specifically address function arguments. Those fall under a more general category of the sequencing of different sub-expressions probably.

Comment: @dyp Thank you for your reference and explanation.

Comment: @Simple *"This might not cover the wording of the order of evaluation"* is probably covered by 1.9/15 "Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
expressions are unsequenced." Normative text, but pretty unspecific

Comment: Thank you for your answer with relevant quotes.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the variadic lambda, the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified as per the language specification (which in turn means the evaluation of `functor(argument)` could be in *any* order unknown to the programmer). That is the only difference. You can search "order of evaluation of arguments" on this site, you will see many topics on it.

As for the variadic templated constructor approach, that should work as long as you use list-initialization to invoke it, otherwise it would have the same problem as the lambda. Note that GCC (upto 4.8.2) has bug, so this doesn't work, though I don't have any idea whether it is fixed with the recent version of GCC.

Comment: Is this rule applied to any variadic function?

Comment: @Constructor: It is applied to any function. Order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

Comment: Oh, I can say now that I have once heard about this. :-) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I know about this strange bug when parameters parameters are passed in the back order.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have a one-liner with no external machinery, you can use a lambda that accepts `std::initializer_list`:

```
template <typename Functor, typename... Arguments>
void IterateThrough3(Functor functor, Arguments&&... arguments)
{
    [](std::initializer_list<int>){}(
        {((void)functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), 0)...}
    );
}
```

Comment: Which could be written as `(void)std::initializer_list<int>{((void)functor(arguments), 0)...};`, I guess.

Comment: @dyp Casting to `void` doesn't turn off the "unused variable" warning on all compilers, passing to a function via an unnamed parameter is more portable.

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that I completely forgot about `std::forward`.  And nobody has corrected me. :-)

Comment: I think there are several possible ways to do something like this. For example: `[](const int(&)[sizeof...(Arguments)]){}({((void)functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), 0)...});` or `[](std::array<int, sizeof...(Arguments)>){}({((void)functor(std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)), 0)...})`. But as @dyp noted it is not so interesting here.

Comment: @Casey I do not construct a variable, only a temporary. So the only warning should be something like "expression result unused", which I guess should be silenced by a conversion to `void`.

Comment: Btw this requires including `<initializer_list>`, so "no external machinery" isn't completely true ;)

Comment: @dyp `initializer_list` is included in almost all standard headers with container classes so it is not the problem here. :-)

Comment: @dyp True, true - "no user-provided machinery", then. I agree about casting the temporary to `void` being better, write an answer and I'll upvote it ;)

Comment: I somehow agree with Yakk's sentiment that we should have a dedicated, well-named tool instead of any of these hideous hacks. -- No offence intended, that applies as well to my suggestion with the temporary.

Comment: @dyp I think that variadic templates themselves (in the form they are presented in C++11 - C++1y) is a rather crude thing. Many obvious and simple tools for working with variadic templates are missing in these standards. An expanding of a parameter pack into a simple operator is only the one of them. Why is expanded pack always comma separated? Why can't I get n-th element of pack in a simple way? Why simple packs like `void f(Type... values){}` are prohibited? A lot of questions and white spots...

Comment: @Constructor That's all been considered, you should maybe read the proposals (and meeting minutes) on [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)

Comment: @dyp Yes, I know that these ideas are in the air... But not in the standard yet, sadly. None of them would get into C++14 as I know. Am I right? And thank you for your reference. I read sometimes [this google group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals) which is devoted to the proposals to the future standards.